# Back substitution for an augmented matrix

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

So let's say I have an augmented matrix $ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&-1&-2\\
  2&-1&3&14\\
-1&-2&1&3
\end{array}
\right] $
and I have to solve for x such that 
$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-1\\2&-1&3\\-1&-2&3\end{bmatrix}$ x $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}-2\\14\\3\end{bmatrix}$.

I started by using Gaussian elimination by putting the matrix into upper triangular form. $ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&-1&-2\\
  0&-3&5&18\\
0&0&-5/3&-5
\end{array}
\right] $ Then in order to solve for x I need to do back substitution but I'm not sure how to do that. The answer for this example is:

x$_3$ = $-5\over-5/3$ = 3

x$_2$ = $18 - (5)(3)\over-3$ = -1

x$_1$ = $-2 - (1)(-1) - (-1)(3)\over1$ = 2

I understand the solution for x$_3$ but what's going on for x$_2$ and x$_1$ and what is the value that's being multiplied in those equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation says

$$-3x_2 +5x_3=18$$

Hence $$x_2=\frac{18-5x_3}{-3}$$

Notice that we have solved $x_3$ earlier.

The first equations say $$x_1+x_2-x_3=-2$$

Hence $$x_1=\frac{-2-(1)(x_2)+(1)x_3}{1}$$

Noticed that we have solved $x_2$ and $x_3$ earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler than that: just proceed till you obtain the R.R.E.F. The solution  is the last column, since the augmented matrix has maximal rank (I suppose the upper triangular form you obtain is correct):
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
  1&1&-1&\!\!\!|\!\!&-2\\
  0&-3&5&\!\!\!|\!\!&18\\
0&0&-5/3&\!\!\!|\!\!&-5
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
  1&1&-1&\!\!\!|\!\!&-2\\
  0&1&-5/3&\!\!\!|\!\!&-6\\
0&0&1&\!\!|\!\!\!&\phantom{-}3
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
  1&1&0&\!\!|\!\!&\phantom{+}1\\
  0&1& 0&\!\!|\!\!&-1\\
0&0&1&\!\!|\!\!&\phantom{-}3
\end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]\rightsquigarrow
&\begin{bmatrix}
  1&0&0&\!\!|\!\!&\phantom{+}\color{red}2\\
  0&1& 0&\!\!|\!\!&\color{red}{-1} \\
0&0&1&\!\!|\!\!&\phantom{-}\color{red}3
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x_2$, from the second equation of RREF, we have

$$-3x_2+5x_3=18 \implies -3x_2=18-5x_3$$

and from here we can solve.

For $x_1$ we can find a similar expression with $x_2$ and $x_3$ at the RHS.

Comment: I see and x3 is the first value we solve for.

Comment: @JoshSusa Yes it is the main feature for triangular matrix to be good! We can solve the system bacward starting from the bottom to the top.